# What are the 3d analyze settings for Splinter cell chaos theory

Tags: 3d-analyze, splinter-cell-chaos-theory

I have downloaded *Splinter Cell: Chaos Theory*, but I am unable to play it. I don't have a graphics card. I managed to play a similar game (*Sand of Time*) using 3D Analyze 2.34, that game too required a graphics card with pixel shader 2.0.

**I tried:**

- Force SW intl
- Emulate pixel shader caps
- Skip pixel shader 2.0

`VendorID 4098: deviceid: 20040`

Please let me know 3D Analyze settings for *Chaos Theory*

Comment: just a -1 but no answer :-/

Comment: An excellent question. +1 and favorited. For the love of God someone please answer this qs. I've tried everything possible to run this game. compatibility modes, 3d analyze, swiftshader, tried updating the game, even tried with different no-cd cracks. The dvd is just lying around in my room these days.

Comment: @Mugen I can run this game nom :) I bought a new laptop with corei7 quad core,8 gb ram, 1gb nvidia 550m graphics card ;)

Comment: Good for you. I too bought a new pc and now I'm able to run the latest games (at full). :)

Comment: `I have downloaded Splinter Cell Chaos Theory...` I sure hope for you you mean Steam or GOG!

Comment: `I don't have a graphics card` - Unless you're using the site via a VT-100 connected to a serial cable I'm fairly sure your computer has a graphics card...

Answer (score 4):

The settings that you need to run Splinter Cell: Chaos Theory using 3D Analyser are;

- Performance -> Force Software Transform and Lighting (TnL),
- Hardware limits -> Emulate Pixel Shader Capabilities

You will also need to install the v1.05 patch or later in order for the game to run through 3D Analyser.

Comment: Just few hours before the world ends I got the answer. :) But I have already bought the laptop which could play this game :P